# Parameterized update SQL query using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a table where two entries has `id = 10`. My SQL update query looks like this:

```
$q = "UPDATE `table_name` SET `col_name` = 'value' WHERE `id` = ?";
if($con-prepare($q)){
    $stmt->bind_param("i","10");
    $stmt->execute;
    $stmt->fetch;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

The query will not run, where is the error in it? And also, when it does run, will it update ALL entries where `id = 10` or just the first one?

Comment: Are you using PDO? mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
```

Do not forget the `()` to show that's a method call else PHP interprets it as a property access.

And write: `$stmt = $con->prepare()` instead of `$con-prepare()` (or do you want to subtract the return of the function call to `prepare()` from `$con`?)

It'll update all the entries with `id=10`